# Parsing with xpath two different classes inside another

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to parse the following html using xpath to retrieve the lsTime and lsTmames to be shown as:

```
21:30
Benfica
Sporting
```

Note that the html has many more data so i will use  a loop.

html:

```
<li class="">
                            <dl class="lsTime"><dd>21:30</dd></dl>
                            <dl class="lsTNames">
                                <dd>Benfica</dd>
                                <dd>Sporting CP</dd>
                            </dl>
                            <dl class="lsScore">
                                <dd></dd>
                                <dd></dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
```

My code:

```
            with Display():
                browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                try:
                   browser.get(url_link_mob)
                   time.sleep(2)
                   for litag in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//dl[@class="lsTime"]'):
                       time= litag.text
                       print(time)
for litag2 in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//dl[@class="lsTNames"]'):
                       clubs= litag2.text
                       print(clubs)    
                finally:
                    browser.quit()
```

If I use the code above  the data won't be displayed as I want because the times for all games will be separate the clubs. How could I parse first the time and then the clubs for each game as shwon in my example? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i am going to reply with pseudocode. TUGA!

```
//cicle all dl elements
for litag in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//dl"]'):
    //assuming the dl have allways the same order,first time then clubs
    //first print the time and then the name
    if(litag.get_attribute(class)=="lsTime")
         time= litag.text
         print(time)
    if(litag.get_attribute(class)=="lsTNames"):
         clubs= litag2.text
         print(clubs)
```

just check what is the function to get attribute from and selenium element in the language that you are using.

Comment: thanks \ obrigado :) Corrected a few things in your code and submitting it as  an answer.

Comment: no problem. off topic, what are you using this for?

Comment: parse live score webpage to get daily alerts (by email) on the matches i am interested in :), not a big deal.

Comment: what is PyVirtualDisplay used for, i am curious because you never know when you will need something like this.

Comment: using  PyVirtualDisplay because I ran web scraping scripts on the cloud (using a paid service). Use it very often for personal projects to not have a machine "always on".

Comment: that is very interesting, can you point me in the direction of some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time

with Display():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    try:
       browser.get(url_link_mob)
       time.sleep(2)
       for litag in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//dl'):
           if litag.get_attribute("class") == "lsTime":
               match_time = litag.text
               print(match_time)
           if litag.get_attribute("class") == "lsTNames":
               teams = litag.text
               print(teams)

    finally:
        browser.quit()
```